# Начинать ли предложение с большой буквы во всплывающих подсказках?

Tags: предложение, локализация

После голосования за закрытие вопроса на всплывающем сообщении по ссылке "закрыть" появляется текст вида:

> Вы проголосовали за закрытие по причине ...

[image: vote close]

С одной стороны - договорились использовать "вы" с маленькой буквы. С другой - тут начало предложения. А с третьей - другие предложения по смежным ссылкам начинаются с маленьких букв.

При ожидании подтверждения правок текст также выводится с большой буквы:

[image: edit wait]

Считаю, что размер первой буквы должен быть согласован с контекстом использования.

В данном случае, предлагаю писать с маленькой буквы:

> вы проголосовали за закрытие по причине ...

т.к. для остальных ссылок сообщения указаны так же с маленькой буквы. Примеры:

[image: edit]

[image: flag]

Ссылки на transifex на всякий случай: [раз](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262843), [два](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267331), [три](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267332).
При этом не очень понял, почему в оригинале с большой буквы ("You"), хотя другие предложения с маленькой (для `edit`, `share`, `flag`).

Answer (score 3):

В начале предложения любое слово должно начинаться с большой буквы, если это не трейдмарк/имя/уникальное обозначение и другой идентификатор (μTorrent,например принципиально начинается со строчной версии) , так что здесь все в порядке. Т.е. это не имеет отношения к спорам о "вы" с маленькой/большой буквы. Правило "первой буквы в предложении" тут приоритетно.

Comment: Т.е. Вы предлагаете и другие хинты сделать с большой буквы?

Comment: да, если они не начинаются с многоточия (являясь шуткой-продолжением_

Comment: Странно, что в комментарии пишите со строчной :) А если серьёзно, это идёт вразрез с большим SO и даже SE.

Comment: Я лично не люблю писать с большой буквы (лень) но если за меня робот (или шаблон) пишет правильно - ок. Правила большого SO/SE  не распространяются на русский язык, в принципе, мы можем принять соглашение, что мы следуем большому SO/SE, нарушая правила русского языка для следования общему style guide. Но тогда вам следует привести ссылки на эти стайл-гайды в вопросе.

Comment: А мне если честно, всё равно, маленькая буква или большая, всё таки это уж очень мелочная проблема

Comment: @Naumov суть не столько в том, чтобы выбрать прописная это будет буква или строчная. А в том, чтобы было единообразно. Сейчас это не так.

Comment: Может и точка в конце нужна в таком случае?

Answer (score 2):

Регистр первой буквы безусловно должен быть согласован в связанных ссылках. Но какой он будет конкретно имеет смысл заимствовать с enSO.